# Server-side Facebook app invites (with Rails and Koala)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

When someone authorizes our app they fill out a form which includes some information and a custom friend selector.  Form is submitted to the server and that's when I'd like to send out the app invites to the selected friends, but there does not appear to be a way without forcing someone to use the client-side request dialog which ruins the experience.

I'm trying this, but I get the OAuthException about the target user needs to accept the TOS before I can send them an invite.  But they can't accept the TOS until they get the an invite to the app!  LOL.

```
oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"])
oauth_token = oauth.get_app_access_token
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
graph.put_object(id_of_friend, "apprequests", {:message=>'user-name wants you to join my app!'})
#=> Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) All users in param ids must have accepted TOS [HTTP 403]
```

How can I generate a server side app invite?

Answer (score 0):

onemanarmy,

I think that you need to use a real friend-id instead the string 'friend-id', this is a number of ten digits and it's the id into facebook of the user that you are trying to request.

I know this because I think that I'm in a further step, but still couldn't get it working. I send the request to users but I can't see the request in facebook. Did you get it working? I'm sending the request to user, but I can't see the request in facebook.

Regards,
Franco.

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question to clarify that.  I discovered it's not possible to send server-side app requests to users who have not authorized the app - you have to use the SDK.